# Как вычитать с помощью спарка полный топик из кафки в batch mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-spark

В гугле на тему spark/kafka попадаются примеры со стриммингом, как я могу в batch моде вычитать данные из кафки используя spark(любое api java/scala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно читать из Kafka-топиков как в потоковом режиме, так и выполнить запрос в пакетном, указывая начальный и конечный оффсеты следующим образом:

```scala
val df = spark
  .read
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribePattern", "topic.*")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(String, String)]
```

Более подробно можете найти в документации: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries